# Is the npm install debug output a standard format, and if so, what is it?

Tags: npm

Upon npm install, logs such as npm WARN ... are outputted.
These seem to be of the same format, but I have also seen npm notice ...
The standard seems to be npm type text followed by a new line.

- Is this correct?
- Is there a list of types?
- Is there a standard listed
  anywhere?

※ I ask this, as I am interested in handling WARN and other events.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any official documentation about logging in npm anywhere.  The best solution to what your trying to do is to find a multitude of use cases and examining the debug log files of each to see what the different types of log messages are (warn, notice, error, info, etc.), and then decide what to do from there.  If you want to start writing a library, take what exists as a starting point and start from there.

You can also request some documentation on the official [npm issues forum](https://npm.community/), which I see you've already done.  It's an idea worth discussing with the community.